# Two triggers and I am getting an error when updating table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I got the two following triggers, each one worked alone, but together they don't.

How can I make them to work together? They update different fields in table.

trigger 1:

```
create trigger wys_sk_u after update on `things`
for each row
begin
UPDATE `current` s 
INNER JOIN things u ON s.id_thing = u.id_thing
INNER JOIN dude_base b ON b.id= s.id
SET s.`curr_cash` = u.cash1 * b.cash2/ 100;
end;
$$
```

trigger 2:

```
create trigger suma_u after update on `current`
for each row
begin
UPDATE `current`
SET `mysum` = `curr_cash` + `mysum`;
end;
$$
```

First one should update when `cash1` or `cash2` updates, and change value of `curr_cash`.
Second should update when `curr_cash` updates, and change `mysum`.

I got following error when I edit table things:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'current' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

@edit
added new answear to the question.

---

What if I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER total BEFORE UPDATE ON `current` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if new.`new_pay_date` <> old.`new_pay_date`
  SET new.`total_cash` = new.`curr_cash` + new.`total_cash`;
end if;
END;
$$
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET new.`total_cash` = new.`curr_cash` + new.`total_cash`; end if;' at line 4
```

This was working without

```
if new.`new_pay_date` <> old.`new_pay_date`
end if;
```

But I need to check this, and only update with date change.

current table:

```
curr_cash
new_pay_date
id_person
id_thing
total_cash
```

Anyone can help me with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the second trigger. Try to use BEFORE UPDATE trigger to change field value using SET statement -

```
CREATE TRIGGER suma_u BEFORE UPDATE ON `current` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.`mysum` = new.`curr_cash` + new.`mysum`;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update a table for for which the trigger is created in the trigger. There is locking mechanism on MySQL so that you can't update the row of the same table triggered the trigger, it can cause recursive call to the trigger and infinite loop.